# Understanding preconditioner for DAE "GMRES" method

Tags: differential-equations, documentation

I am not sure this question is on topic, but I give it a try.

I am reading through the documentation for IDA [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveIDAMethod.html), in particular the section for "GMRES" almost at the end of the page. It says that a preconditioner should be used, but I do not understand the example they use, can anyone explain it?

Comment: I think `pfun[t, Flatten@Array[u, {nx, ny}], Flatten@Array[u', {nx, ny}], c][Flatten@Array[r, {nx, ny}]] // ArrayReshape[#, {nx, ny}] & // MatrixForm` shows the rescaling of the residual the preconditioner represents. My `u[i, j]` represents the function `u` on the discretization over x,y, and likewise for the derivative `u'[i, j]` and residual `r[i, j]`. The IDA manual is [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/sites/default/files/237206.pdf) (see p. 3 and pp. 30f). I don't have experience with preconditioners, so I'm not sure how much help I can give beyond this.

Comment: As a side note, the [NDSolve Options for Finite Elements](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOptions.html) also has a section on iterative solvers. It may be that the in product version of that tutorial is a bit more up to date than the web page.